# SQL Query to present data

Tags: sql

I have the following two database tables

```
TableA

PK_A      FK_B      FK_USER
1         1         userLogin
2         2         userLogin
3         3         otherUserLogin


TableB


PK_B
1
2
3
4
```

What I need is a query that returns the following result for a specific User in this case 'userLogin'

```
Result

   PK_B     PK_A     FK_USER
   1        1        userLogin
   2        2        userLogin
   3        3
   4
```

Be aware that the query must always return all the items that Table B has.

Thanks in advance
Happy holidays

Comment: why isn't otherUserLogin showing on the 3rd output row? Is that what you want? If so how do you know not to show it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.PK_B, a.PK_A, a2.FK_USER
FROM TableB AS b LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA AS a 
    ON b.PK_B = a.FK_B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA AS a2
    ON a.PK_A = a2.PK_A
        AND a2.FK_USER = 'userLogin'
```

The extra `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to TableA is due to the poster's request for output:

```
Result

PK_B     PK_A     FK_USER
1        1        userLogin
2        2        userLogin
3        3
4
```

Where `FK_USER` only returns matches for `'userLogin'`

Comment: Using a WHERE clause turns the outer join back into an inner join. Replace the WHERE with AND to change the condition to be part of the join criteria.

Comment: Yikes, what a miss. Fixed it! Thanks for spotting, @MarkBannister !

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT b.PK_B, 
       a.PK_A, 
       case when a2.FK_USER = 'userLogin' then 'userLogin' end as FK_USER
FROM TableB AS b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA AS a ON b.PK_B = a.FK_B
```